# How to navigate to index.php when instance name is entered in URL section, but block access to files based on extension in Web.config file?

Tags: iis-7, web-config

I have requirement where I blocked the access to files based on extension using below lines in Web.config file for IIS.

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="false">
            <add fileExtension=".php" allowed="true" />
            <add fileExtension=".js" allowed="true" />
            <add fileExtension=".css" allowed="true" />
            <add fileExtension=".png" allowed="true" />
            <add fileExtension=".jpg" allowed="true" />
            <add fileExtension=".gif" allowed="true" />
            <add fileExtension=".jar" allowed="true" />
         </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

But these lines preventing the application from navigating to index.php (home page). How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Add `<add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />` and try again.

Comment: Thank you @LexLi, this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Lex Li's method would achieve your requirement. Besides,  URL rewrite could provide another way to block all unlisted extension based on {PATH_INFO} variable.

```
 <rule name="rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="\.(js|php|css|png|jpg|gif|jar)$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="AbortRequest" />
                </rule>
```